# Framework for send http request in iPHone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

What is the best framework for send Http Post and Get request with JSON?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i would suggest ASIHTTPRequest http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/
there is documentation and examples

hope this will help